# python 3 vector subtraction with out numpy

Tags: python-3.x

I'm fairly new to coding in the python3 language. I'm trying to construct a function that takes two vectors and subtracts them. Any help would be great. Thank you in advance.

Write a function vecSubtract(vector01, vector02) which takes in two vectors as arguments, and returns the vector which is equal to vector01-vector02.

```
def vecSubtract(vector01,vector02):
    for i in range(min(len(vector01), len(vector02))):
        result = [vector01[i]-vector02[i] ]
    return result
vector01 = [3, 3, 3]
vector02 = [4, 4, 4]

print(vecSubtract(vector01,vector02))
```

Answer (score 0):

While you are looping over the vectors (lists actually), you are overwriting your result variable every time.

You probably want to use a list comprehension instead.

```
def vecSubtract(vector01, vector02):
    result = [vector01[i] - vector02[i] for i in range(min(len(vector01), len(vector02)))]
    return result

vector01 = [3, 3, 3]
vector02 = [4, 4, 4]

print(vecSubtract(vector01,vector02))
```

If you really want to use a for loop, you should use `result.append()` instead of overwriting the variable every time.

Also, it is probably not right to allow subtraction of vectors of different lengths by ignoring the surplus elements in the longer vector. Instead you should probably test that the two vectors are the same length and have the script throw an error if they are not.